# How to define a fieldtype with ignore case and whitespacetokenizer

Tags: search, solr

I would like to define a fieldtype in Solr which should have following properties

Ignore case while searching
Ignore whitespace splitting

Tried as follows,

```
<fieldType name="text_lcws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

but it splits the string on whitespaces :-(

Comment: How should it tokenize? Or should it not tokenize at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the tokenizers that are being used. Based on the [Analyzers/Tokenizers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Tokenizers) page on the Solr Wiki, I would recommend using the KeywordTokenizerFactory, as is defined as follows: *"Treats the entire field as a single token, regardless of its content."*

So I would define a field as follows below. Please note that I removed the SynonymFilterFactory as well, not sure if that is really needed, if so, I would recommend putting it as an index time analyzer instead.

```
 <fieldType name="text_lcnows" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
```